# Referencing files included in the FileList attribute in a manifest

Tags: powershell, manifest, powershell-module

I am writing a PowerShell module that will perform various configurations on our product including some xml transformations.
So, I need to include the XDT files in my module.
My module manifest will include the FileList attribute with a list of all the transformation files.
But the question is, how do I reference these files in the functions in the module?

Didn't find much in the documentation except that the FileList is just an inventory.
I thought of creating a variable with a path to the files (dynamic of course, depending on where the module is installed) but there must be a way to use these files...

This is a script module, not binary module and intended for V5

Thanks!